# Wrong Values being shown in the columns in my view. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have a process where I am imputing/substituting data when loading from a CSV/XML. Whenever a value is 'imputed'/'substituted' I flag the original (invalid) value with a ***'IMP'*** code in the **DATA_CODE** column. I then insert the 'imputed' (or 'substituted') value with a ***'ORG'*** code in the **DATA_CODE** column. 
Below is some sample data:

```
  VALUE        HOUR                 HOUR_NUM        CONT       TYPE     DATA_CODE
    777     09-SEP-18 02:00:00 PM       1             SMP        SUM     ORG
    -48     09-SEP-18 02:00:00 PM       1             SMP        SUM     IMP
     99     09-SEP-18 03:00:00 PM       2             SMP        SUM     ORG 
      0     09-SEP-18 04:00:00 PM       3             SMP        SUM     ORG
  94181     09-SEP-18 05:00:00 PM       4             SMP        SUM     IMP
    842     09-SEP-18 05:00:00 PM       4             SMP        SUM     ORG
   null     09-SEP-18 06:00:00 PM       5             SMP        SUM     IMP
    842     09-SEP-18 06:00:00 PM       5             SMP        SUM     ORG
```

I need a view that looks like the one below:

```
HOUR                    HOUR_NUM   CONT      TYPE    IMPUTED_VAL   ORIG_VAL
09-SEP-18 02:00:00 PM   1          SMP       SUM     777           -48
09-SEP-18 03:00:00 PM   2          SMP       SUM     null           99
09-SEP-18 04:00:00 PM   3          SMP       SUM     null           0
09-SEP-18 05:00:00 PM   4          SMP       SUM     842            94181
09-SEP-18 06:00:00 PM   5          SMP       SUM     842            null
```

I've tried the following:

```
select HOUR
     , HOUR_NUM
     , CONT
     , TYPE
     , MAX(CASE WHEN (data_code IN ('IMP', 'SUB') AND TYPE <> 'FAKE')
                THEN value
                ELSE null
                 END)    AS               IMPUTED_VALUE
     , MAX(CASE WHEN (data_code NOT IN ('IMP', 'SUB') OR data_code is null OR TYPE = 'FAKE')
                THEN value
                ELSE null
                 END)   AS                ORIG_VAL
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY HOUR, HOUR_NUM, CONT, TYPE;
```

However, I am returning results where the IMPUTED_VAL and ORIG_VAL are switched. Even when I switch the logic for the two columns I am still receiving the following results:

```
HOUR                    HOUR_NUM   CONT      TYPE    IMPUTED_VAL   ORIG_VAL
09-SEP-18 02:00:00 PM   1          SMP       SUM     -48            777
09-SEP-18 03:00:00 PM   2          SMP       SUM     null           99
09-SEP-18 04:00:00 PM   3          SMP       SUM     null           0
```

Not sure if this is enough information but thought it wouldn't hurt to reach out as I've been stuck on this for quite some time now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the first row of your desired results, how are you expecting an input of 777? The row with a datacode of ORG has a value of -48... (you've also misspelled 'input', by the way)

Comment: IMPUTE is the correct word :) Also we are expecting 777 because whenever a value (i.e. -48) is deemed 'invalid' the original value is flagged with 'IMP' and a new value (777)  is derived and inserted as the 'Imputed Value'. Does that make sense?

Comment: So in your table, values with a datacode of 'IMP' are actually the original values, and values with a datacode of 'ORG' are actually the imputed values? Shouldn't you just update your query to reflect that?

Comment: only when an imputation has to take place. that way when I do calculations / sum up the values later I am grabbing the 'imputed value' rather than the 'original' (but invalid) value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get what you're asking because the data  in the table looks right for what you wrote. First `Imputed_val` would be -48 because `data_code` is in `'IMP'` and 777 would be in `Orig_val` because it isn't in `'IMP'` or `'SUB'` This looks right. If you need it switched around it would just be the opposite case statements for each column.

```
select DISTINCT tb1.HOUR
     , tb1.HOUR_NUM
     , tb1.CONT
     , tb1.TYPE
     , (CASE WHEN (tb1.data_code IN ('IMP', 'SUB') AND tb1.TYPE <> 'FAKE')
                THEN (SELECT tb2.value
                      FROM table1 tb2
                      WHERE tb2.hour = tb1.hour
                      AND tb2.data_code IN ('ORG'))
                ELSE null
                 END)    AS               IMPUTED_VALUE
     , (CASE WHEN (SELECT tb2.data_code
                   FROM table1 tb2 
                   WHERE tb2.hour = tb1.hour
                   AND tb2.data_code IN 'IMP') IS NULL 
                   OR tb1.data_code IN ('IMP') or data_code IS NULL or TYPE = 'FAKE')
                THEN value
                ELSE null
                 END)   AS                ORIG_VAL
  FROM Table1 tb1
  GROUP BY HOUR, HOUR_NUM, CONT, TYPE;
```

In this case I just switched the IN and NOT IN statements and got the results you wanted. You may also want to change the TYPE too?

Comment: the issue with this is when the value is negative I return the wrong values :(

Comment: since I'm using 'MAX' (i think)

Comment: Why would a negative value effect the return value? It seems that this is more of a problem with how the data is entered in the system. Then a Issue with extracting the data into a different table. The program is going to take your query literally and not take into account for negative values unless you write it that way. You could `CASE WHEN value < 0` but I don't see how that will give you a true representation of the data. If you can explain why negative values give you the wrong value. Or explain what this query is doing I could help you more.

Comment: So right now I am substituting (or imputing) a value when it's too big (i.e. 10x the historical maximum value) or if it's a negative value. If I deem that the imputation/substitution is needed, I am loading two values into the original tables in the database. One original (but 'invalid') value which will be flagged as 'IMP' and one IMPUTED (or calculated) value which will be flagged as 'ORG' . The reason I have these swapped in a non intuitive way is because when I do groupings later I am going to want to group the imputed values along with the values that didn't need imputation but have 'ORG'

Comment: I think another contributing factor to the issue is that when an 'imputed' value exists, we are going to want to classify the imputed value as 'imputed' and original value as 'ORIG_VALUE' in the View but if there isn't an imputed value we will have null as the imputed value. But the flaggings say otherwise (counter-intuitive I know)

Comment: so imputed_values will never be in the negatives correct?

Comment: I can add more data if it would help. Correct: Imputed_values will never be negative.

Comment: sure that would help add some data and I'll see if I can make better sense of it.

Comment: More data has been added

Comment: one more question is there ever going to be multiple ORG or IMP values for each hour or is it if values need to be imputed theres just one imp and one org value for each hour?

Comment: I edited my previous answer try that out let me know what it does I'm actually at work myself and don't have time to create a table to run through SQL fiddle to see if it works. But it should. Sorry it took so long I did run a version of this on my own oracle database and for some reason it didn't run right until i added the prefixes to the tables. Also if it doesn't work with `tb1.hour = tb2.hour` then try `tb1.hour_num = tb2.hour_num` might actually work a little better now that i think of it

Comment: No problem! Thanks so much! Let me try it now